# enclosing scope

Tags: c++

what's wrong with this code?

```
class matrix{ 
private:  
   friend transpose(const matrix&);  
   friend class invert;  
   public: //...
};  
matrix (*p)(const matrix&)=&transpose; //error: no transpose() in scope.
```

what does the statement means "a friend declaration does not introduce a name into enclosing scope".This problem does not occur when friend keyword is removed

Comment: First thing, your `transpose` is missing its return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the declaration of transpose() as a friend and without the friend declaration is that if you declare "friend transpose()" all you are doing is telling the compiler that a function friend with the signature shown in the friend declaration can have access to the private members of an object of type matrix. It does *not* declare a function transpose() with this signature - you still have to do this outside the scope of the matrix class.

If you remove the 'friend' keyword, you are declaring a member function transpose() inside the class matrix, so the compiler actually has seen a function it can take the address of.

Answer (score 1):

`§7.3.1.2 [namespace.memdef] p3`

> [...] If a `friend` declaration in a nonlocal class first declares a class or function the friend class or function is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. **The name of the friend is not found by unqualified lookup or by qualified lookup until a matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope** (either before or after the class definition granting friendship). [...]

See also [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8207633/500104).

Comment: if we only declare not define a friend function in enclosing scope then it would work or not? what if we only declare it in enclosing scope and not declare it

Answer (score 0):

1. Friend functions are functions that are not members of a class but
   they still have access to the private members of the class.
2. I should point out that a friend function declaration 
   may be placed in either the private section or the public section,
   but it will be a public function in either case, so it is clearer to
   list it in the public section.

> ```
> class MyClass
> {
> private:
>   int data;
> public:
>   MyClass(int value);
>   friend void myFriend(MyClass *myObject);
>
> };
>
>  void myFriend(MyClass *myObject)
>  {
>    cout << myObject->data<< endl;
>  }
>
> MyClass::MyClass(int value)
> {
>   data = value*2;
> }
>
> int main()
> {         
>   MyClass myObject(3);
>   myFriend(&myObject);
> }
> ```

So, you need to define the friend function after you declare it.