# What/where is the scope of friend functions definition defined in class template?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the scope of inline friend functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207633/whats-the-scope-of-inline-friend-functions)

Consider simple program :

```
template<typename T> struct foo{
friend void bar(){}
};

int main(){
foo<int>(); foo<float>();
}
```

Above code breaks the ODR rule, I wonder why? , also where is the scope of function `bar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`friend` functions are not member functions; you just declare friendship inside a class, but the function is always a free function. If you define it inside a class template class, you will end up defining it as many times as template instances you have.

I will try to explain that with code. For our purposes, your code is equivalent to this:

```
template<typename T> struct foo{
};

template<> struct foo<int>{
  friend void bar();
};

void bar() {};

template<> struct foo<double>{
  friend void bar();
};

void bar() {};

int main(){
  foo<int>(); foo<float>();
}
```

Comment: so the scope of `bar` is global scope in the above case ?

Answer (score 1):

Because your code defines the free function `void bar()` twice, or lets rather say, your templates produces for each instantiation a new function named `void bar()`, which happens to have the exact same signature each time, therefore you have multiple functions with the same signature, which is a breach of ODR.

The technique at hand is called "Friend Name Injection", because you inject a name into the surrounding namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You have **defined** the `bar` inside your `struct`. This leads to double definition of `bar` func, once per template instantiation. `Friend` should be only a declaration of some entity. The entity itself (func in your case) should be defined elsewhere. Replace your `bar` definition with `friend void bar();` declaration and define your `bar` in another place.

Comment: please read the question again, ofcourse there are two def in same unit  but what is the scope of bar?