# c++ inline friend function with same name as member variable

Tags: c++, inline, member, friend, friend-function

This surprised me. This works:

```
struct foo {
  int x;
  friend int x(foo f) { return f.x; }
  friend int y(foo f);
};

int y(foo f) { return x(f); } // no problem
```

But this is an error:

```
struct foo {
  int x;
  friend int x(foo f) { return f.x; }
  friend int y(foo f) { return x(f); } // error: invalid use of foo::x data member
};
```

Why aren't both of these (dis)allowed?

Comment: Does `return ::x(f);` work? That should explicitly reference the `x()` in the global namespace. (If `x()` is not in the global namespace then try `::the::namespace::x(f)`.)

Comment: @cdhowie: "The name of the friend **is not found** by unqualified lookup **or by qualified lookup** until a matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope".  Argument-dependent lookup is the only way to find it, or add a declaration above the class (since below the class is too late for an inline declaration of `friend int y()` to find it)

Comment: What kind of naming convention leads to a member variable and a friend function to share a name? That is the issue you really need to solve.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that in the first case, the friendship injected the function declaration into the enclosing namespace, so the global-scoped call to `x` can see only one `x`.

In the second example, `x` has *two* meanings at that scope: The global friend function and the variable (which presumably shadows the global friend function).

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8284809/103167, no you cannot call it as `::x(f)`.

Comment: Ben is correct, unless you also provide a declaration at namespace level you can only reach the friend function through ADL.