# C++ - Overloading operators that accept abstract classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I've ran into some trouble while trying to solve a simple problem for my C++ class.

I have two classes: `Component`, an abstract class from which I inherit other classes and `List`, a class that has a list of Components (it is not a template class). I want to overload the `operator+`. so that when I "add" two components, it will return a `List` containing both `Components`.

I've done so using this, which shows no errors:

```
friend List operator +(Component &c1, Component &c2) {
        List l;
        l.push(c1);
        l.push(c2);
        return l;
    }
```

However, when I try to "add" two objects of classes that are inherited from Component, I get the following error:

```
no match for 'operator+' in 'c1 + c2'
```

Here is how I add the objects:

```
Inherited1 c1(1, 2, 3);
Inherited2 c2(1, 3.2, 10);
List l1 = c1+c2;
```

Comment: [This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/792b5213c9ec09d4) and it's fundamentally what you've shown. There's definitely an element of a non-reproducible problem here.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Unless you are actually implementing a DSL you should preserve the arithmetic meaning of operators.

Comment: `operator +` takes `Component&`, you are sending `Inherited`, how will it work?

Comment: @RakibulHasan, Because it's a derived class.

Comment: you need to add definition of function out of the class .

Comment: @omid, My example does not, but still works.

Comment: @chris But he say Component is abstract class. Maybe is problem here.

Comment: @NejcGalof, Good point. Allow me to amend my example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23a13931b2680d26

Comment: @chris I think Component isn't abstract class but is derived class from some abstract class.

Comment: @NejcGalof, I don't get that impression, but it shouldn't make a difference either way. Of course if the OP produced an MCVE instead of me, we wouldn't be having this discussion.

Comment: @omid you are right I thats how it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The friend function is not defined outside class hence the compiler is not able to find operator+. The friend func operator+ should be defined outside the List class.

As you have not posted the complete structure of classes, I have assumed and tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;


class Component{

    public:


};

class List{

    list<Component> l;
public:

   void push(Component& c)
   {
       l.push_back(c);
   }
  friend List operator +(Component &c1, Component &c2);

};

class Inherited1:public Component{

    public:
    Inherited1(int x,int y,int z){}

};

class Inherited2:public Component{

    public:
     Inherited2(int x,int y,int z){}  


};

 List operator +(Component &c1, Component &c2) {
        List l;
        l.push(c1);
        l.push(c2);
        cout<<"called"<<endl;
        return l;
    }



int main()
{

    Inherited1 c1(1, 2, 3);
    Inherited2 c2(1, 3.2, 10);
    List l1 = c1 + c2;

    return 0;
}
```

I assume that you have operator+ func inside your List class as shown below because of which you are getting error :

> error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘Inherited1’ and ‘Inherited2’)
>      List l1 = c1 + c2;

---

```
class List{

    list<Component> l;
public:

   void push(Component& c)
   {
       l.push_back(c);
   }
  friend  List operator +(Component &c1, Component &c2) {
        List l;
        l.push(c1);
        l.push(c2);
        cout<<"called"<<endl;
        return l;
    }

};
```

Comment: What are you actually saying?

Comment: The why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207633/whats-the-scope-of-inline-friend-functions

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have added what I really meant with some text.