# Type conversion in ostream& operator <<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup, friend-function

I have a class `entry` and an `ostream& operator <<` overwritten for it. I also have an auxiliary class `cursor` and a type conversion `operator entry()`.
Then, in my `main()` function I have the following expression:

```
cout << data[4];
```

where `data[4]` is a `cursor`, but compilation fails with

> error: invalid operands to binary expression

What I want is for a compiler to convert `data[4]` to `entry` and to use its `<<` operator.
Is there any way to call this ostream operator in an aforementioned way without having to add special methods to `entry`?

Here are some pieces of code:

```
    class entry
    {
        friend class cursor;
        /*here comes some data*/

    public:    

        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const entry& a);
    };
```

```
    class cursor
    {
        database* data_;
        size_t ind_;
        friend class entry;
        friend class database;

    public:
        cursor (database* a, size_t ind);
        cursor (const cursor& a);
        void operator= (const  entry x);
        void operator= (const cursor a);

        operator entry();           //type conversion
    };
```

and here is what I use in main():

```
    cout << data[4];
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal self-contained example?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The short answer is "no".   There are other threads describing why an implicit conversion of `data[4]` to an `entry` will not be performed in this case, although I don't have time right now to fine one and flag this question as a duplicate

Comment: @Brian sure, I've added an example

Comment: "MCVE" means that someone else can copy and paste your code and compile it without making any changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write:

```
class entry
{
    // ...
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const entry& a);
};
```

Although this declares `operator<<` in the enclosing scope, the name lookup rules say that name lookup in that scope does not actually find this function! (Because it has only been declared via `friend`).

If a function has only been declared via `friend`, then the only way it can be found is via argument-dependent lookup. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207633/whats-the-scope-of-inline-friend-functions) for more detailed explanation of the lookup rules.

The function would be found by:

```
entry e;
cout << e;
```

because ADL sees that there is an argument of type `entry` and so it searches functions that are associated with `entry` (including friends declared there).

However, `cursor c; cout << c;` does not include `entry` in its search list (even though a conversion from `cursor` to `entry` exists).

---

To fix this you need to provide a non-friend declaration of the operator, that is visible at the point of `main`.  For example:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const class entry& a);

class entry
{
    // ...
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const entry& a);
};
```

NB. I chose to put the declaration before the class instead of after, because this is also the best way to solve the *template friends* problem.

Comment: Thank you! Haven't thought about that