# How to declare a template function a friend of a templated nested class?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

How can I make `get` a function in the enclosing scope that can access the private constructor of `outer<T>::inner<U>`?

```
template <typename T>
struct outer {
    template <typename U>
    class inner {
        inner() {}
    public:
        friend inner get(outer&) {
            return {};
        }
    };
};


int main() {
    outer<int> foo;
    outer<int>::inner<float> bar = get<float>(foo);
}
```

I have tried declaring it out of class by making `inner` have a `template <typename V, typename W> friend inner<V> get(outer<W>&);` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have tried declaring it out of class by making `inner` have a template `<typename V, typename W> friend inner<V> get(outer<W>&);`

You need to declare the template function before the friend declaration, to tell the compiler that `get` is a template. E.g.

```
// definition of outer
template <typename T>
struct outer {

    // forward declaration of inner
    template <typename U>
    class inner;
};

// declaration of get
template <typename V, typename W> 
typename outer<W>::template inner<V> get(outer<W>&);

// definition of inner
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
class outer<T>::inner {
    inner() {}
    public:
    // friend declaration for get<U, T>
    friend inner<U> get<U>(outer<T>&);
};

// definition of get
template <typename V, typename W> 
typename outer<W>::template inner<V> get(outer<W>&) {
    return {};
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xalhANCorlXzGqYk)

Comment: God that is gross.

Comment: Actually, a friend definition is usually only accessible via ADL unless it has an out of class declaration prior. Is there a way to achieve the same effect here?

Comment: @user975989 You mean you don't want to provide an out-of-class definition?

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering if that's possible. Sorry I mean declaration NOT definition. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207633/whats-the-scope-of-inline-friend-functions

Comment: @user975989 For your case (i.e. `get`) it's impossible. As you said, without a out-of-class declaration it can only be found by ADL. But `get` doesn't take parameter with type `inner`, ADL won't help either. (Yes I know you meant out-of-class declaration, it doesn't change the conclusion.)