# What's the use of a friend function in a struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, friend

I'm overloading the insertion operator (<<) inside a struct using the following syntax:

```
struct Address{
    string street;
    string cross;
    int suite;

    friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &oss, const Address &other){
        oss<<"street: "<<other.street<<"cross: "<<other.cross<<"suite: "<<other.suite;
        return oss;
    }
};
```

I see that only if I declare the function as a friend of struct 'Address' does my code compile. As per my understanding a friend function is useful when there's a need to access the private members of a class. But, since in a struct all the members are public, there shouldn't be a need to declare the '<<' operator as a friend.

Could anybody please clarify the need of declaring '<<' operator here as a friend of the struct 'Address'?

Comment: 1) "_But, since in a struct all the members are public_" One can have `private` members in a `struct`. 2) Yes, there's no need to have the function as a `friend`, in **this** case.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Answer in the answer section please, not here

Comment: CppCon 2018: Dan Saks “Making New Friends”  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POa_V15je8Y

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My comment, as-is, isn't a decent answer. Decent answer would need to better formatted, and not be as brief. I am, just to lazy, at the moment, to improve it, in those ways.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius You do not have to post an answer, so if you do not think you can write a full one, you can simply post nothing! But putting it here is not the way to work around that. Thanks

Comment: Without `friend`, it becomes a member function - like all other inline function definitions.

Comment: It is particulary usefull in case of two classes accepting the same (one) parameter in nonexplicit constructor as explained by Nico Josuttis  [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-_TLTdLGtc) (around mark 28:00)

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, that operator can be defined at namespace scope without `friend`.

You do not "need" to make it a `friend` in this case, for exactly the reasons you give, so it's not clear where you've heard that you do!

```
struct Address
{
   string street;
   string cross;
   int suite;
};

inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& oss, const Address& other)
{
   oss << "street: " << other.street << "cross: " << other.cross << "suite: " << other.suite;
   return oss;
}
```

*(I made it `inline` on the assumption you're keeping the whole definition in the header, though in reality I'd probably declare it in the header then define it elsewhere.)*

However a class defined with `struct` is still just a class and can still contain `private` members just fine. If you had one that did, you would once again need a `friend`.

Some people may choose to *always* make a `friend` function for consistency, and so that the definition of `operator<<` looks like it's "in" the class when you read it. Alternatively there may be some arcane lookup constraints that make this convenient (since a `friend` function defined in this way can only be found by ADL), though I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: Does that mean the only difference between a struct and a class in c++ is that by default all members in a class are private while in struct they are public?

Comment: @ShubhamUrkade Yes

Comment: @ShubhamUrkade Actually, there is no such thing as "a struct" in C++; the keyword `struct` gives you a class. But close enough.

Comment: The inline friend function can be found only by Koenig lookup. One *may* have practical reasons to make it so. Prevent name collision in other places, maybe? I can't really think of an example off the top my head. Point is, I'm not sure it's right to say this is always about style.

Comment: @StoryTeller Hmm could be an interesting point. I'm not going to investigate but I'll pay lip service to it and feel free to edit something in if you find something :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Had a feeling ;)

Comment: This operator declared in global scope should probably be declared `inline`, in order to match the code in the question. And also because the class is presumably defined in a header. (Or the operator could be defined outside of the header, if we don't mind deviating from the code in question).

Comment: @eerorika Thank you

Comment: @StoryTeller: One case of useful `friend` is for template classes, allowing non template functions to use the template struct, `template<typename T> struct S {friend void foo(S, T) {/*..*/}};` and `foo(S<char>, 42)` (`42` used as `char`).

Comment: @eerorika Could you please explain the reason for making it inline?

Comment: @ShubhamUrkade Non-inline functions (that are used) must be defined in exactly one translation unit (as per *One Definition Rule*). Header files are typically included into multiple translation units, and therefore it is usually not OK to define non-inline functions in header files. When a function is defined inside a class definition (as you did), it is *implicitly* inline. When a function is defined in namespace scope (as in this answer), the function is implicitly non-inline. Thus the need for explicit inline declaration here.

Comment: @StoryTeller: about the "strange" friend lookup and the reasons why one may desire it, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52122453/214671 may be interesting. The paper linked in the answer is particularly illuminating (and shows some really dark corners of C++).