# Friend Function definition inside class

Tags: c++11

When I try to implement friend function inside the class as shown below, I get an error, and I don't know why... It only happens when a non-argumental friend function is declared inside the class. The error is

> display() is not defined in this scope

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test{

    private: 
    int x = 5;


    public:

    friend void display(){
        test obj;
        cout << obj.x << endl;

    }
};


int main(){


    display();

    return 0;
}
```

Output should be simply: 5

But I get this error:

> display is not defined()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207633/whats-the-scope-of-inline-friend-functions

Comment: but it is declared as friend ...so no class instance is required....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the scope of inline friend functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207633/whats-the-scope-of-inline-friend-functions)

Comment: friend functions are not instance functions but still can access private members; that's why they are special functions. Think it this way, if you will declare the function inside the class as an instance method, you are already getting to access the private members, then why you need to make it friend

Comment: Rule of thumb, friend functions are always non-instance functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to do this, but if you have to, define the display() method outside the class.

```
class Test
{  
   private: 
      int x = 5;

   public:    
      friend void display();
};

void display()
{
    Test obj;
    cout << obj.x << endl;
}

int main()
{   
    display();    
    return 0;
}
```

Though in general, I try to avoid friend classes/functions.  I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I'd rethink your approach.