# Call an inline friend from a method instead of itself

Tags: c++, friend

```cpp
struct P {
  int x, y;

  friend P operator-(P u, P v) { return {u.x - v.x, u.y - v.y}; }

  friend int cross(P u, P v) { return u.x * v.y - u.y * v.x; }
  int cross(P u, P v) const { return cross(u - *this, v - *this); }
};
```

The method is an infinite loop (it will call itself instead of the friend).

Is there any way to get around this issue without changing the interface (the names)?

Comment: Why does the friend have to be defined inline? Is it because you want it to be hidden from ordinary name lookup?

Comment: When I run your code, I get this compile error ```"error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘P’ and ‘const P’)"```.  Do you have any compile error ? If not, can you show us your whole program ?

Comment: In the member function, explicitly call the non-member (friend) function.   For example, `int cross(P u, P v) {return ::cross(u - *this, v - *this);}`.      [Note:   I'm assuming that is what you intend the effect to be.].

Comment: In this particular case, the friend does not need access to P's internals. But I didn't see a simple way to define the global before (it needs P to be declared) or after (it breaks the method) either :/
@Peter that is what I intend, but the compiler won't find ::cross with just this fix

Comment: Simple: *don't call the member function `cross`*. It's confusing as hell and if you ask me to do a code review, it goes down, no ifs or buts. Leave the name `cross` for the friend and invent another name for the member. Better yet, ditch the member altogether and add another friend with 3 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with a declaration inside the member function:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
  friend int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  int add(int a, int b) const {
    int add(int, int); // function declaration
    return add(a, b);  // call that declared function
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  printf("%d", foo.add(1, 2)); // prints 3
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/41KbWWh6P)

Comment: The linker isn't finding `add(int, int)` in this example, but I'll see if I can tweak this.
Also note I need the friend function to take Foo as an argument

Comment: @elbrunovsky use GCC 11.0 or later (or clang 8.0 or later). As you can see from the demo I shared, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two member functions with the same name and the same signature in a `struct` (or `class`).

One solution is to move the `friend` function out of the `struct`, so that it can be referred to with a global namespace specifier `::`

```
#include <iostream>

int cross(int i) { return 42; }

struct P {
    friend int cross(int i);
    int cross(int i) const { return ::cross(i - 1); }
};

int main() {
    P p = {};
    std::cout << p.cross(7) << std::endl;
}
```

The original code produced two warnings, very descriptive:

```
1 > 1.cpp(6, 25) : warning C4514 : 'cross' : unreferenced inline function has been removed

1 > 1.cpp(7) : warning C4717 : 'P::cross' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
```

Re: `without changing the interface (the names)` - you could simply rename your friend function and even make it private; it is not a part of the interface.

Comment: You omitted a problem of having `P` as parameter to `cross()`, but this may be solved by changing parameter type to (const) reference and defining the global `cross()` below `P` (and adding a couple of forward declarations). [See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U1rJE4inGbKYgEtY)

Answer (score 0):

`Ayxan Haqverdili`'s answer seems to be cleanest possible, and [abides by the ISO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284809/8658157). However, pre-`gcc 11.0` and pre-`clang 8.0` appear to have bugs that [cause this to fail](https://godbolt.org/z/zb4oG3Gq3).

Luckily in this case there's an alternative that uses [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl):

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    friend int Bar (Foo)
    {
        return 13;
    }
    friend int RedirectToBar (Foo);
    
public:

    int Bar (Foo)
    {
        return RedirectToBar(Foo());
    }
};

int RedirectToBar (Foo)
{
    return Bar(Foo());
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << Foo().Bar(Foo()) << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xjceohq3h)

Keep in mind that this only works because some of the arguments to the function are an associated class.

If that's not the case and you ***really want*** to keep this design and ***really need*** compatibility with older compilers, then we can add in a dummy associated class without breaking the interface by adding it as a default parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

int RedirectToBar ();

class Foo
{
    struct Key {};

    friend int Bar (Key = Key())
    {
        return 13;
    }
    friend int RedirectToBar ();
    
public:

    int Bar ()
    {
        return RedirectToBar();
    }
};

int RedirectToBar ()
{
    return Bar(Foo::Key());
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << Foo().Bar() << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4KeG4b79z)

However, it's important to add that all of this is a big code smell. Although I don't know the real-world problem of the OP, this seems like a terrible hack to get around bad design choices.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this solution similar to Peter's and Yksisarvinen's:

```
struct P {
    int x, y;

    friend P operator-(P u, P v) { return P{u.x - v.x, u.y - v.y}; }

    friend int cross(P u, P v);
    int cross(P u, P v) const;
};

int cross(P u, P v) { return u.x * v.y - u.y * v.x; }
int P::cross(P u, P v) const { return ::cross(u - *this, v - *this); }
```

Not quite sure yet why the compiler doesn't find `::cross` if I write it inside of `P`.

Note, there is one potential drawback: we have to specify the return type of both functions (can't have it deduced with `auto`), but this was not needed in this case.